# chrome devtools media query breakpoints is integrated as only one media size

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools

This is my Sass code,

I test this several times and confirm media query works

but In Chrome devtools, only one(75em) media query(about max-width) appears..

```
//mixin for media queries
@mixin for-phone {
    @media (max-width: 37.5em) { @content }; // 600px
}
@mixin for-tab-port {
    @media (max-width: 56.25em) { @content }; // 900px
}
@mixin for-tab-land {
    @media (max-width: 75em) { @content }; // 1200px
  }
@mixin for-big-desktop {
    @media (min-width: 112.5em) { @content }; // above 1800px
}
```

```
// main.scss
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; // 1rem = 10px, 10/16 = 62.5%

  @include for-tab-land {
    font-size: 56.25%; // 1rem = 9px, 9/16 = 50%
  }

  @include for-tab-port {
    font-size: 50%; // 1rem = 9px, 9/16 = 50%
  }

  @include for-phone {
    font-size: 30%; // 1rem = 9px, 9/16 = 50%
  }

  @include for-big-desktop {
    font-size: 75%; // 1rem = 9px, 9/16 = 50%
  }

}
```

I struggle this with for over three days. and not yet find the problem is.

as you can see below screenshot in the Source panel, there are 3 media size in the source code

but only 75em is showing.

please help me....

[image]

Comment: There is a reported issue for this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1175687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome Dev or Chrome Canary works. (both are developer version of Chrome)

As you can see below screenshot, multiple max-width media query are showing up

[image]